# Error: origin_mismatch when authorizing embed API for Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to implement a statistics dashboard from google analytics in a 3rd party CMS and I'm running into some problems. I'm trying to use googles embed API to build my dashboard and run into this error when I try to authenticate my account:

```
Error: origin_mismatch
```

I have looked around for a solution and found out it was because of a missing `www.` pretty quick. The thing is that I filled out the right URL in googles developer console and still have no luck. Does anyone know how I can fix this to work properly?

```
Error: origin_mismatch

Application: CMEZ Analytics

You can email the developer of this application at: email@email.com

Request Details
=
from_login=1
response_type=code token id_token gsession
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
redirect_uri=postmessage
cookie_policy=single_host_origin
proxy=oauth2relay482041337
include_granted_scopes=true
origin=http://cmez.eu
state=458516662|0.59538506
as=1d7def2550073266
client_id=[censored]
authuser=1
hl=nl
That’s all we know.
```

Comment: so the request details show an origin of "http://cmez.eu". Is this listed in the API Console as one of the permitted origins for your app?

Answer (score 0):

The `origin_mismatch` errror is probably caused by the Javascript origins not being set correctly in the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) for your project. The Javascript origins must match the domain from which your requests are coming and to which you are returning the user after sign in.

Note: A common mistake here is to add javascript origins for http:// but not https:// (or vice versa). You must also include the port number of your server in the javascript origins if a port number appears in the url.

[Documentation info](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/javascript)

> In the Authorized JavaScript origins field, enter the origin for your
>   app. You can enter multiple origins to allow for your app to run on
>   different protocols, domains, or subdomains. Wildcards are not
>   allowed. In the example below, the second URL could be a production
>   URL.
>   http://localhost:4567 
>   https://myproductionurl.example.com